# Update/Change value in a ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am still quite new to java programming and I am looking for some help with my java exercise, currently I am having trouble to figure out how to update a value in a ArrayList.

I have used JAXBinding to generate some source files that I can use it to create XML file.

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
 String delete;
 AvailableFlights todayFlight = new AvailableFlights();
 List<Flight> flights_today =  todayFlight.getFlightDetail();

Flight journey1;
        journey1 = new Flight();
        journey1.setJourney("J1");
        journey1.setAirline("KLM");
        journey1.setConnections(1);
        journey1.setDestination("Amsterdam");
        journey1.setOrigin("London");
        journey1.setSeats(10);
        journey1.setCost(200);
        journey1.setCurrency((float) 0.16);
        flights_today.add(journey1);
```

The problem I am finding that is if I want to update the `Seats` value, I would do something like this to take away a seat:

```
if(delete.equals("J1")) {
Flight journey1;
flights_today.add(journey1.setSeats(-1));
flights_today.add(journey1);
}
```

But it just overwrites it with -1 instead of taking 1 seat off from 10.

**Problem Solved with :** `journey1.setSeats(journey1.getSeats()-1);`

Comment: journey1.setSeats(journey1.getSeats()-1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using:

`journey1.setSeats(-1)`

You should use:

`journey1.setSeats(journey1.getSeats()-1)`

`setSeats(-1)` will set the number of seats to -1, you should specify the actual value instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `set(index, value)` in order to update a value of a class implementing the `List` interface, including `ArrayList`.

Comment: I have tried that and it doesn't seems to like it, what I have done is remove void types on the Flight.class on the setters and returns it. Then I try use this `flights_today.set(1, journey3.getSeats());` and getting this error "`method set in interface List<E> cannot be applied to given types;
  required: int,Flight
  found: int,int
  reason: actual argument int cannot be converted to Flight by method invocation conversion
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in interface List`"

Answer (score 0):

When you're taking away a seat, you need to:

- Find the correct flight by iterating through the list and finding the correct `Flight`.
- On this flight you want to `setSeats` by subtracting 1 from the `getSeats` value.